# Understanding an example about Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have two questions about the following example taken from Palka's "An introduction to complex function theory". I highlighted with red the parts that I don't understand.

1. Why does the first equality in 5.11 hold?
2. Since $r \to \infty$, won't we have that eventually the disk $\Delta$ won't encompass $| \gamma |$? (where $|\gamma|$ is the curve parametrized by $\gamma$). I think we cant't make $\Delta$ bigger because it would contain $-i$ and $f$ must be analytic in $\Delta$ to apply the local Cauchy's integral formula.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the integration paths lives in $\Im z \ge 0$ (half-circle plus real segment) so it's not going to contain $-i$ regardless of how big it is - figure $14$ shows this quite clearly as you always can take a disc that lives mostly in the upper half-plane

Comment: This example is an application of the local Cauchy's integral formula in Palka's book, which I just added to my question. It supposes $f$ is analytic in an open disk $\Delta$, not in an unbounded region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^r\frac{\cos t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\int_{-r}^r\frac{\cos t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$ because the integrand is an even function. $$\int_0^r\frac{\sin t}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=0$$ because the integrand is an odd function.

I'm not sure I understand what your second question is.  Are you thinking that the center of the disk remains fixed as $r$ increases?  This isn't so.  No matter how big $r$ gets we can construct a disk that includes the segment $[-r, r]$ and doesn't contain $-i$.

**EDIT**

More specifically, we can construct a circle passing through the points $-r, r, \frac{-i}2$.  (The center will lie on the positive imaginary axis.)  Now if we increase the radius by some $0<\varepsilon<\frac12$ the circle will look like the one in Figure $14$.  As $r$ increases, the center of the circle we construct will travel "north" on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Will it still be a disk having $-i$ as "south pole"?

Comment: @Twink I don't know what you mean, but it will look like Figure $14$ above.

Comment: The south pole, like in the sphere. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SouthPole.html It would be the minimum $y$ coordinate of the circle. Would that be always $-i$?

Comment: @Twink No, $-i$ would never be on the circle.  Again, it always looks like Figure $14$.

Comment: I mean the circle $\partial \Delta$

Comment: @Twink Yes, that's the circle I'm talking about.  Perhaps you can edit your question to make what you are asking clear.  I don't follow.

Comment: I was just trying to say formally that it looks like figure 14.

Comment: I thought that when $r$ gets bigger, the circle $\partial \Delta$ would get so big that it wouldn't have $-i$ as a its south pole. But know I understand we can always construct a cirlce like in figure 14. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

$$\int_0^r \frac{\cos t \, dt}{t^2 + 1} = \int_{-r}^0 \frac{\cos t \, dt}{t^2 + 1}$$
because the integrand is even. Adding the two sides together and dividing by $2$ will equal the left-hand side.

Meanwhile, $$\int_{-r}^r \frac{\sin t \, dt}{t^2 + 1} = 0$$
because the integrand is odd.

---

Regarding your second question: the application of Cauchy's integral formula holds as long as $\Delta$ is an open set containing $\gamma$ but not $-i$. You are right that as $r \to \infty$, the circle described in the proof will not work, but you can replace it with something else, like $\{z : \Im(z) > -1/2\}$.

Comment: But this example is an application of the local Cauchy's integral formula in Palka's book, which I just added to my question. It supposes $f$ is analytic in an open disk $\Delta$, not in an unbounded region.